# Inserting wrong data in to the database with $wpdb->insert

Tags: php, mysql, wordpress

So hey guys!

I currently have a code that gets data from a custom table called wp_refundrequests, and prints them as a table to the page. On the page the admin can either Accept, or Deny the request by pressing a button on the side of each order. Denying the request just deletes the request from the table, but accepting should delete it from the current table and insert the information to the next table called "accepted requests".

The wp_refundrequests table contains customer's order that they want to refund.

The code that gets the info and prints it:

```
global $wpdb;
$requests = $wpdb->get_results("SELECT * FROM wp_refundrequests", ARRAY_A);

foreach ($requests as $row) {
echo "<div class='requests'>" . "<li class='refunds'>" . "Palauttajan nimi: ".
$row['customer_name'] . "</br>" ."Palautettavat tuotteet: ".$row['product_name']."<br> "."Määrä: ".
$row['product_qty'] . " "
. "<br>Kommentti: " . $row['comment'] . "<br> " . "Hinta: " . $row['refund_total'] . "€ " .
"<br>" . "Päivämäärä: " . $row['request_date'] . " " .
"<a class='right' href='admin-page?deleteid=" . $row['request_id'] . "'>Deny</a></li>" .
"<li class='refundaccepts'><a href='admin-page?acceptid=" . $row['request_id']
. "'>Accept</a></li>" . "</div>";
$_SESSION['custname'] = $row['customer_name'];
$_SESSION['prodname'] = $row['product_name'];
}
```

With my current code, the "Accept" button deletes it, and inserts information in to the new table, BUT the information that is inserted is wrong. It seems like it wants to either insert the latest data that had been inserted in to the wp_refundrequests table to the wp_acceptedrequests, or it keeps the data from the latest refund request and tries to insert that instead because for example as seen here(Sorry for the bits of Finnish as well):

[image: Table]

If I were to click the "Accept" button on the above, older one, the query would still insert it like this:
[image: Insert query]

So it basically inserts the info from the latest refund_request insert and inserts that instead of the one selected. However the one that had been selected still gets deleted from the table.

Here's the code that is triggered when the user clicks on "Accept"

```
$custname = $_SESSION['custname'];
$prodname = $_SESSION['prodname'];
if(isset($_GET['acceptid'])) {
$accept = $_GET['acceptid'];
/* Query to do whatever here */
$wpdb->print_error();
$wpdb->insert("wp_acceptedrequests", [
  "customer_name" => "$custname",
    "name_product" => "$prodname",
    "date" => date("Y/m/d/G:i:sa") ,
]);
$wpdb->print_error();
$wpdb->query("DELETE FROM wp_refundrequests WHERE request_id = $accept");
}
```

I have to say I have no idea why it doesn't want to insert the selected request, please comment if there's something confusing, I'll try to clear it up then.

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You redefine $_SESSION with in foreach loop so at the end of foreach it will equal to the last one, pass each row parameter to it is accept link like this

```
 "<li class='refundaccepts'><a href='admin-page?acceptid=" . $row['request_id']."&custname=".$row['customer_name']."&prodname=".$row['product_name']."'>Accept</a></li></div>";
```

Then call it the same way you get $accept-ID

```
if(isset($_GET['acceptid'])) {
$accept = $_GET['acceptid'];
$custname = $_GET['custname'];
$prodname = $_GET['prodname'];
```

Note:Iuse my phone so make sure if it was a syntax error in the href part of the code

Comment: When I tried this, not sure why but it doesn't want to print the requests into the site, it just comes as a blank for some reason.

Comment: Right click and select view page source and check if the parameters passed to the url in accept link

Comment: It seems to be getting the right parameters, however it's calling that the $custname and $prodname are undefined, nothing else to notice I don't think.

Comment: echo $_SERVER['QUERY_STRING'];  Try this and see if parameter passed correctly , there is no reason that acceptid passed correctly and the other not passed

Comment: I feel pretty dumb right now, but it doesn't output anything, just a blank.

Comment: Looking more into it, it looks like it only gets the acceptid parameter, and nothing else

Answer (score 0):

Please try like this and comment out the session variable.

```
if(isset($_GET['acceptid'])) {
  $accept = $_GET['acceptid'];
  $accepted_requests = $wpdb->get_results("SELECT * FROM wp_refundrequests WHERE id = $accept", ARRAY_A);

  if( !empty($accepted_requests) ) {
    $insert = $wpdb->insert("wp_acceptedrequests", $accepted_requests);
    if($insert) {
      $wpdb->query("DELETE FROM wp_refundrequests WHERE request_id = $accept");      
    }
  }
}
```

Comment: A good way but with one problem which is solving the problem with this way need more database query which consume more time

Comment: Hmm, the insert doesn't want to work, it just doesn't happen for some reason.

Comment: @Puppe what is the structure of your "wp_acceptedrequests" table?

Comment: I hope this is clear enough, since I can't post a picture here :D

request_id, int(20) AI,
product_name, long text,
product_qty, int(3)
comment, longtext
customer_name, varchar(50)
refund_total, varchar(10)
request_date, datetime
request_status, varchar(50)

Comment: @MahfuzulHasan This works, but it doesn't insert the query information since it says the value would be 0,